# Spring batch call getNextException() in JdbcBatchItemWriter

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

We have e a small batch project with spring boot and spring batch.

We are using a `JdbcBatchItemWriter`with a db2 database. However, when an error occurs, we got the following error message:

> Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.BatchUpdateException: [jcc][t4][102][10040][3.63.123] Batch failure.  The batch was submitted, but at least one exception occurred on an individual member of the batch.
>   Use getNextException() to retrieve the exceptions for specific batched elements. ERRORCODE=-4229, SQLSTATE=null

Unfortunately, to have a clear error message, I need spring to call the `getNextException()` to have details about the precise exception. However, I have checked the code of the class `SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator` and it doesn't look like Spring offer some functionalities for that.

Has anyone found a solution for this problem without rewriting the class `SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be handled by checking the list of Exceptions returned by: **getAllFailureExceptions()** , after **jobLauncher.run()** ends.

```
 List<Throwable> exceptions = execution.getAllFailureExceptions();
                for (Throwable throwable : exceptions) {
                   //code to handle nested exceptions
                 }
```